# How to get database values by week

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I just want to ask how can I achieve getting the records in a database by week in a month? using sql
What I really mean is when I input 1 it will get the records in 1st week of a month 
I've done a lot of research today but it seems I can't find a good solution

Heres the code:

```
DECLARE @MONTH int
DECLARE @YEAR int
DECLARE @WEEK int

SET @MONTH = 9
SET @YEAR = 2013
SET @WEEK = 1

SELECT RH.RepairOrderNumber FROM dbo.RepairOrderHeader RH
WHERE MONTH(RH.DateReleased) = @MONTH AND YEAR(RH.DateReleased) = @YEAR AND WEEK(RH.DateReleased) = @WEEK
```

I just want to fetched the records according to month,year, and by week is there any way and precise code on how to do this?

Comment: I need this because I have a report that require this

Comment: need more information, lets say a week starts in jan and ends in feb. Do you want the whole week or just the part that match the declare month ? How do you define the first week of the month ?

Comment: I want the whole week example sept 29-oct5 that is define as a week

Comment: It is best to avoid using functions like `MONTH()` on your date columns. [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/) has written a [very good article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) about best practices when handling date range queries, it is probably worth a read.

Comment: for performance(correct date handling) you should have picked @GarethD's or my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATEPART(WEEK,)` gives you number of a week in an YEAR so you just need to calculate number of week in the month calculating difference between current date week number and the week number of the first day of the month:

```
WHERE MONTH(RH.DateReleased) = @MONTH 
  AND YEAR(RH.DateReleased) = @YEAR 
  AND DATEPART(WEEK,RH.DateReleased)
       -DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(RH.DateReleased)+1,RH.DateReleased))+1 
       = @WEEK
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is intended behaviour, but if you change the DATEFIRST it makes the range less than a week, e.g. with datefirst of 3 the range returned is 1st - 3rd September ([Example on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a834c/9))

Answer (score 0):

`WEEK` returns the week of the year, starting on a constant day of the week (i.e. each Sunday). You seem to want the week of the month, which I guess would always start on the 1st of each month.

so:

```
SELECT RH.RepairOrderNumber FROM dbo.RepairOrderHeader RH
WHERE  MONTH(RH.DateReleased) = @MONTH AND 
       YEAR(RH.DateReleased) = @YEAR AND 
       DAY(RH.DateReleased) / 7 + 1 = @WEEK
```

Answer (score 0):

Where possible avoid using functions on columns in the WHERE clause. You immediately lose the ability to take advantage of indices on these columns. The below solution gives the same results as the select answer, but performs much better:

```
DECLARE @MONTH INT = 9
DECLARE @YEAR INT = 2013
DECLARE @WEEK INT = 2

--1ST OF THE MONTH DECLARED
DECLARE @Date DATE = CAST(CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(4)) + 
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + '01' AS DATE)

SET  @Date = DATEADD(WEEK, @Week - 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @Date), @Date));

SELECT  RH.RepairOrderNumber 
FROM    dbo.RepairOrderHeader RH
WHERE   RH.DateReleased >= @Date
AND     RH.DateReleased < DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @Date);
```

All this does is get the first of the month in question, then find the first day of the week that the first of the month falls in. Then adds the declared number of weeks to this date.

With an example table with 6 years of data in and 10 rows for each day (20,480 records, so not a lot) and an index on your date column the execution plans of this and the accepted answer are as follows (Accepted on top, using dates on the bottom):

[image]

*[Testing DDL and queries on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a834c/1)*

This shows that when you use `WEEK(DateColumn) = @Week` that the index is not used at all, and the query cost is much higher. Depending on the distribution of data in your table this could make a massive difference, even in the small set of data in my example it is 800% more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I consider '2013-08-26' - '2013-09-01' the first week in september

```
DECLARE @MONTH int = 9
DECLARE @YEAR int = 2013
DECLARE @WEEK int = 1

DECLARE @from date= dateadd(day, datediff(day, -(@WEEK - 1)*7, 
       (dateadd(month, (@year-1900) * 12 + @month - 1 , 0)))/7*7 , 0)

SELECT RH.RepairOrderNumber 
FROM dbo.RepairOrderHeader RH
WHERE RH.DateReleased >= @from
and RH.DateReleased < dateadd(week, 1, @from)
```

Comment: I agree with your interpretation that the first week in September is 26th August - 1st September, however only if Monday is your first day of the week, if Wednesday is the first day of the week then I would argue that the first week in September is 28th August - 3rd September. Your query does not account for this and no matter what `DATEFIRST` is set, it still returns the same time span. [Demo on SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a834c/9)

Comment: @GarethD my weeks are like iso_week, they always start on monday. Your query rely on the firstdate setting of the server. That would be a problem on all our servers. I always write my queries so they don't depend on that. which is why I didn't upvote your answer. You will never see any answer from me that uses firstdate